# JavaScript result.error not display in HTML

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

My JSON file will return 2 difference values.

If record exist, JSON will return:

```
[{"ic":"000000000001","name":"SITI"}]
```

If record not exist, JSON will return:

```
{"error":"No Record."}
```

For the record exist, I managed to display the value in HTML, but why when the error value, it does not display the "No Record." in my HTML?

Javascript code:

```
callApi(operation, "72eafd5c6bab3fdc731f395675f7b9483729ef", "get", configObj).then(function (result) {
  result.data.forEach(function (v) {
    if (result.error) {
      var error = v.error
      $(".result").show()
      $(".value.error").text(error)
    } else {
      var name = v.name
      var ic = v.ic
      $(".result").show()
      $(".value.name").text(name)
      $(".value.ic").text(ic)
    }
  })
})
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="result">
  <div class="separationLine"></div>
  <div class="label custom_secText">
    <center>DISPLAY HERE..</center>
  </div>
  <span class="value error"></span>
  <p>Name : <span class="value name"></span></p>
  <p>IC : <span class="value ic"></span></p>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Comment: can you print the result.data in console for both the condition ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you dont get inside the if statement. Have you debugged ii or placed a console.log inside this if statment?
Does it help if you change this part

```
if("error" in result) {
```

?

Comment: Adding `code` if("error" in result) {`code but not display the error message.

Comment: You have to show us exactly what is inside your result variable